# Include AuthnContextDeclRef in the AuthnRequest

Tags: spring-saml

We have a requirement to support more than one login page for multiple SPs.
One login page will be a default, and the others will be Service Provider specific, so for instance:
SP1 will have a default configuration, and authn request will resolve to the default login page maintained in the IDP.
SP2 will ask for a login page B in the authn request, which the IDP must oblige.

Ordinarily this should be configurable at the IDP end, warranting no changes to the SPs, however this "feautre" is not supported in our IDP.
Thus our IDP support folks have recommended we include

```
<samlp:RequestedAuthnContext Comparison="exact">
<saml:AuthnContextDeclRef>blah/blah/blah</saml:AuthnContextDeclRef>
</samlp:RequestedAuthnContext>
```

In the authn request. 
Spring SAML does provide us with an option of configuring the Comparison attribute via WebSSOProfileOptions ; however I'm struggling with AuthnContextDeclRef.

One solution which I have tested successfully is to extend the WebSSOProfileImpl class and override the buildAuthnContext method, however I'm wondering if there is a better solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend class `WebSSOProfileImpl` and override method `buildAuthnContext`, where you can programatically add the `AuthnContextDeclRef` elements you need.

You can also open a [feature request](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SES/component/10711/), or contact commercial support of Spring SAML.